# Retry in python methods

Tags: python

This is the standard language-neutral approach

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__file__)

class SomeClass(object):
    max_retry = 2

    def get(self, key):
        try:
            return self.__get_value(key)
        except Exception:
            logger.error("Exception occured even after retrying...")
            raise

    def __get_value(self, key, retry_num=0):
        try:
            return self.connection().get(key)
        except Exception:
            logger.error("Exception occured")
            if retry_num < self.max_retry:
                retry_num += 1
                logger.warning("Retrying!!! Retry count - %s", retry_num)
                self.__get_value(key, retry_num)
            else:
                raise
```

Is there any better **pythonic** way to do this?

Comment: Replacing recursion with a simple loop would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaner approach would be not to change state of the class since it's retry just for the function call (current implementation wouldn't work as expected when the method is called multiple times). I'd prefer a retry decorator (as loop with break when succeed) used as:

```
...
@retry(n_times=2, catch=Exception)
def get (self, key):
    ...
```